# Trying to prevent duplicate item on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, sorting

I have a JSON DB I am working with. After you click an item on the page, it shows that items contents on the page. At the bottom I have a similar product for each item. After you click the similar product it refreshes the page with that new items contents.

The similar products are randomized and added to a new array called "categoryItems". I am pushing items based on the item commodity and brand to this new array. It also checks the DIV "productTitle" and looks for that keyword in the DB. If it matches, it shows that category. The problem I am having is that sometimes the random item matches the item that is already on the page. I have included a code pen below. If you click the similar product a few times you will see that it eventually matches what is already on the page. I need someway to prevent this. Hopefully someone will understand what I mean thanks!

[Link to CodePen](http://codepen.io/tcarp/pen/aBPLqX)

```
//show similar product
var categoryItems = [];
//filter random product by product title
var prodTitle = $('#productTitle').text();
$.each(json, function(i, item){
    if (prodTitle.indexOf("Tomatoes") !=-1) { 
        if(item.itemCommodity == '1120' && item.itemBrandLetter == "C") categoryItems.push(item);
    }
});

var similarProduct= '';
$.each(json, function(i,item){
    similarProduct = categoryItems[Math.floor(Math.random()*categoryItems.length)];
    similarProduct = '<div>' + '<a href="#" class="showProduct"' + 'data-itempageurl="' + similarProduct.itemFullUPC + '"' + 'data-itemgmo="' + similarProduct.itemGMOFree + '"' + 'data-itembpa="' + similarProduct.itemBPAFree + '"' + 'data-itemgluten="' + similarProduct.itemGlutenFree + '"' + 'data-itemlowsodium="' + similarProduct.itemLowSodium + '"' + 'data-itemorganic="' + similarProduct.itemOrganic + '"' + 'data-itemimage="' + similarProduct.imageURL + '"' + 'data-itemname="' + similarProduct.itemName + '"' + 'data-itemoz="' + similarProduct.itemPackSize + '"' + 'data-itemdescription="' + similarProduct.itemDescription + '"' + 'data-itemupc="' + similarProduct.itemFullUPC + '"' + '>' + '<img class="img-responsive img-hover similarProductImagesCategory" src="' + similarProduct.imageURL + '">' + '<h3 class="similarProductSubCategoryImgCaption">' + similarProduct.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
});
$('#productSimilar').append(similarProduct);
```

Comment: check this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqgKjJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your problem but if your problem is just that sometimes the similar product and the product displayed , you just need to check if they have the same reference, for instance :

```
    $.each(json, function(i, item){
        if (prodTitle.indexOf("Tomatoes") !=-1) { 
            if(item.itemCommodity == '1120' && item.itemBrandLetter == "C" && prodTitle !== item.itemName) { // Added comparison between prodTitle and item.itemName
categoryItems.push(item);
 }
        } });
```

Here is a example with your product title, but you should check with the production reference.

I hope this will help you

**EDIT 1 :**
You are welcome :-)

By the way, why are you going threw your whole JSON after if you want only one similar product ?
You can replace this piece of code

```
var similarProduct= '';
$.each(json, function(i,item){
    similarProduct = categoryItems[Math.floor(Math.random()*categoryItems.length)];
    similarProduct = '<div>' + '<a href="#" class="showProduct"' + 'data-itempageurl="' + similarProduct.itemFullUPC + '"' + 'data-itemgmo="' + similarProduct.itemGMOFree + '"' + 'data-itembpa="' + similarProduct.itemBPAFree + '"' + 'data-itemgluten="' + similarProduct.itemGlutenFree + '"' + 'data-itemlowsodium="' + similarProduct.itemLowSodium + '"' + 'data-itemorganic="' + similarProduct.itemOrganic + '"' + 'data-itemimage="' + similarProduct.imageURL + '"' + 'data-itemname="' + similarProduct.itemName + '"' + 'data-itemoz="' + similarProduct.itemPackSize + '"' + 'data-itemdescription="' + similarProduct.itemDescription + '"' + 'data-itemupc="' + similarProduct.itemFullUPC + '"' + '>' + '<img class="img-responsive img-hover similarProductImagesCategory" src="' + similarProduct.imageURL + '">' + '<h3 class="similarProductSubCategoryImgCaption">' + similarProduct.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
});
```

With

```
var similarProduct= '';
var randomProduct= {};
    randomProduct= categoryItems[Math.floor(Math.random()*categoryItems.length)];
    similarProduct = [...]//Keep ur stuff but use randomProduct instead of overwriting your similarProduct, your code will be more readable
```

Comment: this seems to work great! wow it was such a simple fix I didnt even think of doing that but thank you soo much!

Comment: thank you. I am still learning still stuff as a go but I appreciate the suggestion!